# Eclipse can't see Java SE 7 directory structure (and neither can I) after install on OSX 10.7.4

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-7

I recently installed Java SE Development Kit 7u5 on my Mac running Lion version 10.7.4. At install the I take the only installation option available which is to install for all users on this computer.

I've tried following several guides in order to get it set up properly with Eclipse but to no avail. I'm following [this Oracle guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-for-mac-readme-1564562.html#eclipse). As it stands Java SE 7 is at the top of the Java Preferences list (so it takes precedence over other versions). Also running `java -version` in Terminal gives the correct result. However when I try to add the JDK to Eclipse as per the guide mentioned above the directory structure  "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home" simply isn't there :

[Here is a link to a screenshot of my directory structure after installing](http://i45.tinypic.com/30jlfcy.png)

I've tried selecting a greyed out 1.7.0.jdk but obviously it's not selectable. If I just try and go ahead with the "JavaVirtualMachines" directory Eclipse doesn't recognise it as a root folder. I've also looked in the Library path from my user folder but also doesn't have the required structure.

On a side note it worries me that no course I've been on teaches you how to deal with all these quirks ... and why hasn't this seemingly trivial process been simplified .... Should I be finding it this confusing to get a SDK working with an IDE?

If anyone knows of any courses please do let me know!

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste the path `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home` directly into the "JRE Home" text field instead of browsing to the directory (Step 5 in the Oracle guide)

Alternatively, you can choose the "Standard VM" instead of the "MacOSX VM". There, you can also browse to the JDK directory.

Answer (score 1):

Faster and easier solution, assuming you've installed the JDK:

- Go to Eclipse Preferences>Java>Installed JREs
- Click the "search button" in the right nav window
- Voila! It should find it.
- Check the box to use as default (if desired) and click "OK" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I followed Stefan Fersti's advice by pasting the path although the path he had wasn't the correct one for me. I used: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home`

I guess the easiest way is to head to the directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and see which update/name your specific folder has.